# how can I copy the bytes from numpy.save to stdout?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some python that needs to send a pickled numpy array to stdout.  If I try to

```
numpy.save(sys.stdout.buffer, data, allow_pickle=False)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thoth/work/TandbergLabs/2022/iot-rendezvous/picture-server/src/main/resources/com/ericsson/duluthMadScience/pictureServer/histogram.py", line 29, in <module>
    numpy.save(sys.stdout.buffer, data, allow_pickle=False)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in save
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 502, in save
    format.write_array(fid, arr, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 689, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: obtaining file position failed
```

What writable file-like object can I pass to `numpy.save` that I can later fetch bytes from?

Comment: `pickle.dumps` uses the `np.save` format.  The resulting string is just a bit longer than the equivalent `npy` files.

Comment: Strange, I cannot reproduce this behavior (on macOS)

Comment: i cannot reproduce this behavior on windows either ... what version of numpy as you using ?

Comment: What version of `numpy` are you on?

Comment: On windows, `sys.stdout` doesn't have a `buffer` attribute.

Comment: @hpaulj it does have a `buffer` attribute on windows, i just tested it on python3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write to [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) buffer then write it to stdout or even transfer it over network.

```py
import numpy as np
import io
import sys
buffer = io.BytesIO()
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
np.save(buffer, arr, allow_pickle=False)
bytes_value = buffer.getvalue()
print(bytes_value)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes_value)  # prints it in non-human readable binary
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any file-like object if the file has been opened in `binary mode` it seems.

You can see this in examples such as this one from the numpy.save [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html):

```py
import numpy as np

with open('test.npy', 'wb') as f:
    np.save(f, np.array([1, 2]))
    np.save(f, np.array([1, 3]))
with open('test.npy', 'rb') as f:
    a = np.load(f)
    b = np.load(f)
print(a, b)
```

Notices that both when opening and reading the file, it passes the character 'b' to second function parameter:

```py
with open('test.npy', 'wb') as f:
....
with open('test.npy', 'rb') as f:
```

This signals to the `open` function to open the file in `binary mode`, you can see more details about this in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Hope that was helpful!